# What are the grammatical name and function of ‘five months later’?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles, measure-phrases

What is the grammatical name and function of *five months later* as used in the following sentence?

> Five months later, Steve strained himself to mould some more blocks.

Answer (score 4):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> It's an adverb phrase functioning as a temporal adjunct. The head word is the adverb "later", which is modified by the noun phrase "five months".